# Passing variable from one page to form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a two page  A and B.  A has a html file which pulls out information from database table called display. database has a field called title.A has a link button that link  B from  A. B is the page that has a form in it  When i click the linked button in  A . It need to go the B and place the title of  A in the input form of  B. I tried to pass a variable but i couldnot sucedd.

For  A i have done this to pass a variable in link.

```
<p>

<a href="{{ URL::action('pageBcontroller@show',[$display->title =>'title']) }}" title="PageB">Page  B</a>

</p>
```

In controller file i have written this method

```
   public function showTitle($title){
        return Theme::view("B")->with('title',$title);
    }
```

Then I have changed the router.php to

```
Route::get("/B/{title}", "BController@showTitle");
```

In the page B my form code looks like this

```
<input type="title" name="title" value="$title" placeholder="title" />
```

I expect to fetch the title from page a and place into pagee B. I am not getting any error but it is not showing as expected.

Comment: change this `value="$title"` to `value="{{$title}}"`

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('pageBcontroller@show',['title' => $display->title]) }}" title="PageB">Page  B</a>
```

Controller Code

```
public function show($title){
        return Theme::view("B")->with('title',$title);
        // or return view("B", ["title" => $title]);
    }
```

Page B View HTML

```
<input type="title" name="title" value="{{$title}}" placeholder="title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel's blade templating engine then you should include each variable you passed in like `{{ variable }}`

In your case it should be `value="{{ $title }}"` in the input tag.